# Rest Service and JMS message in a single transaction

Tags: spring, rest, transactions, spring-jms

I am having a spring JMS listener , which is doing some message processing , calling rest web service and posting a message to other JMS queue. 
What I want is to happen it in a single transaction . For example , in case while posting a message to JMS queue , if something goes wrong how can we rollback rest service call  ?
(I am not sure how can  we enlist web service calls in transaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. ReST (HTTP) is not transactional.

The best you can do is issue a compensating request to undo the update.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Just for the curiosity , just in case , had it been SOAP service was there any way to make it transactional ?

Comment: No; it makes no difference; SOAP (normally) runs over HTTP so the same applies. Even if you run SOAP over JMS, you would have to commit the send (so the service can see the message).